# Mutator returning a value

Tags: java

Mutator returning a value

Add a new method emptyMachine() to the TicketMachine class that is designed to simulate emptying the machine of money
It should both return the value in total and reset the value of total to zero.
Paste the whole method into the space below

```
public int emptyMachine()
    {
        System.out.println("# " + total );
        total = 0;

    }
```

i get this error:

```
TicketMachine.java:44: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
The output should have been:
    emptyMachine() returns correct value
    emptyMachine() empties machine

This is what was actually produced:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TicketMachine
```

Comment: As the compiler says. You miss the return statement. You method must return an int

Comment: Just randomly typing in statements until the checker is happy is a very inefficient way to learn how to code, even if the oracle called StackOverflow gives you the solutions. If you want to learn to program, you'd be much better advised to actually attempt to understand the meaning of variables, methods and return statements.

Comment: You have set return type to "int" but you did not return a value.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions: *""It should both return the value in total **and** reset the value of total to zero.""*

That's easy. In this case the **"and"** can only be usefully read as **"as well as"**.

```
public int emptyMachine()
{
    int prevTotal = total;
    total = 0;
    return prevTotal;
}
```

Win \o/ !

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, you are missing a return statement in your method - which must return an int value

How to use the [Java return statement](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=280)

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature declares that it returns an int, but you don't return anything at all.

```
public int emptyMachine()
{
    System.out.println("# " + total );
    total = 0;
    return total;
}
```

I have to assume that the variable 'total' is defined outside of the method because you do not show us that code.

Comment: public int emptyMachine()
    {
        System.out.println("# " + total );
        total = 0;
        return total;
    }

you mean that?

Comment: Mark: 0 out of 1

Comments:

    * Test 1 (0.0 out of 1)

          The compilation was successful
          The output should have been:
              emptyMachine() returns correct value
              emptyMachine() empties machine

          This is what was actually produced:
              # 300
              # 0
              emptyMachine() empties machine

Comment: @Tical:  I just added that as an instructional type of thing, but yes, the OP's assignment was to return 'total'.